# how to send partial source data attributes to different targets

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am building an integration between a source and two targets, here source data object has 10 attributes ,  of which one target needs around 6 attributes and another target needs 4 attributes only, appreciate any help here on how i can achieve with spring

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the source to send the Message to a `PublishSubscribeChannel` .

Then configure two [Transformers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/message-transformation.html#transformer) to subscribe to this pub-sub channel. One of the transformer will transform the message the 6 attributes version while other to the 4 attributes version. Both transformers will then send the transformed messages to a separate channel .The two target system will look for the messages sent to these separated channels and process them.

In term of annotation configuration , it looks like the following: (Assuming the message the source sent out is `Foo`)

```java
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel pubSubChannel() {
        return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel outputChannelWith4Attributes() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel outputChannelWith6Attributes() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }


    @Component 
    public class MyTransformer {

        @Transformer(inputChannel = "pubSubChannel", outputChannel = "outputChannelWith4Attributes")
        public Foo transformTo4Attribute(Foo foo) {
            //do the transformation logic here
            return result;
        }

        @Transformer(inputChannel = "pubSubChannel", outputChannel = "outputChannelWith6Attributes")
        public Foo transformTo6Attribute(Foo foo) {
            //do the transformation logic here
            return result;
        }
    }
```

And configure the source to send the message with payload `Foo` to `pubSubChannel` .Also configure the targets to process message from `outputChannelWith4Attributes` and `outputChannelWith6Attributes`.